# Database Design - Linking two users

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I need some help with some database design. I am a FE developer by trade and have only dealt with very basic DBs. I am just starting to branch out into more "advanced" web apps and would like some pointers in the right direction for the schema.

What I am looking for is an account system that can basically link two accounts. I will give you the scenario I had imagined off the top of my head.

A user signs up in a regular way, just providing name, email, password for simplicity of this question. After they have signed up, the user can then link their account to another user by entering the others email and having it accepted by the other user.

Once this link has been created, the two users can CRUD tasks together.

The bit I am struggling with is how to create the link between the two users. I obviously have my users table.

```
USERS:
 id
 name
 email
 password
```

Now, I believe I need to create another table that holds the two linked accounts, that has its own unique ID that we can use to CRUD tasks. Something like:

```
LINKED_USERS:
 id
 user1id
 user2id
 verified

TASKS
 id
 lu_id (FK, Linked_Users id)
 // Any other fields for the two combined here.
```

Is this correct? If so, how would I setup the relationships between the users table and the linked_users table? This is the bit that is confusing me because I need the relationship to reference two users IDs. Say I wanted to display user1id and user2id names, how would the relationship work? Just really need a bit of help wrapping my head around this.

I hope this makes sense, if you need any more information I will just edit the question.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: The foreign key "lu_id" will associate a Task to exactly 2 people. Can 3 users work on a task together?

Comment: Not in this case. It will always just be 2 people :)

Comment: Is a person only ever linked to one other person? Or can a person have other links as well? Another question… A pair can own one or more tasks?

Comment: A person is only ever linked to one other person :) In response to your other question, a pair can own only their own tasks but many of those. For example, if I was linked with you, we could create, read update etc... as many of our own tasks that we have created but we could not access or even see tasks that another pair has made. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question in not entirely clear as to the requirements. My design assumes the following about requirements:

- People are linked together in pairs
- Each pair owns zero, one, or more task records.
- Each person can be assigned to zero, one, or more pairs. If not currently, then perhaps over time (past pairs, current pairs, future pairs).

I think your confusion revolves around the pairing. Instead think of it as teams. The fact that a team can have at most two people is beside the point; 2, 10, 100 does not matter because any number is handled the same way. That way is a Team table that has members assigned. Each person can belong to one or more teams, and each team can have one or more members. That means we have a [Many-To-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between Person and Team. A many-to-many is a problem in relational design that is always solved by adding a third intermediate or "bridge" table. In this case, that bridge table is `membership_`.

Each team owns zero, one, or more tasks. Each task is owned by one and only one team. This is a simple [One-To-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many) relationship between Team and Task.

If these assumptions and constraints are correct, then you would have the following table design in a [relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).

I added a `start_` and `stop_` pair of fields on `membership_` to show the idea that people may have past, present, or future assignments to teams.

[image: ERD Entity-Relationship Diagram for table design]

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. There is only one thing left that is confusing me and that’s the logic behind when the team and membership table gets populated. I will explain what I mean below:

Comment: A user signs up which populates the `person_` table. This user then requests to link to another user by entering their email.  What happens at this point, before the other user has accepted to join the team? Does this populate one entry into the `team_` table and puts the user who sent the request into the `membership` table with the newly created team id? Once the other user accepts, it then populates another row in the `membership_` table? If you could shed any light, that would be great! Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @DavidReid Upon the initiation of an invitation, one record in `team_` is created and two in `membership_`. You define a `status_` field on the `membership_` table, marking the one linking to our subject as "inviter" and the other one linking to the the invited person as "invitee". When the invitee person later accepts, you change the `status_` of that `membership_` row from "invitee" to "accepted". Later on, if a person quits that team, you change the `status_` to "quit".