# Database schema: how to implement feedback from users?

Tags: sql, database-design, postgresql-9.1

I have table 'users'. Users can have roles - 'client' and 'employee'. Clients can give employees feedback (rating). I am not sure, how to implement it correctly, since clients and employees are one entity in schema (users).

I thought about something like this:

[image: a img]

So, if a user has role 'client' then he will have feedback through 'given_feedback', and if 'employee', then through 'received_feedback'? Is it appropriate way to do it?

It is alike to this question: [Database Design - Linking two users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460198/database-design-linking-two-users) though in my case it is important to know who gave the feedback and who received it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

### users

```
id
first_name 
last_name 
email 
role_id
etc..
```

### feedback_users

```
id
user_id
given_feedback - a value that tells if it's given (1) or recieved feedback (0))
feedback_text
```

### roles

```
id
name
```

(two rows with client and employee)

### Relations between above tables:

```
users.id - feedback_users.id (1 to many)
users.role_id - roles.id (many to 1) //given that a user can only have one role
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - ah of course. changed in answer.